# How can I embed a variable that updates every time the command is run?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py

I am trying to get my discord bot (coded in python) to embed the contents of a string variable that I set up.
I am unable to figure out how to make the bot embed the string, as well as how to make the variable update every time the command is run.

I made a function for the playerlist variable in the hopes that it would run every time I called it, but I wanted for some guidance on whether this is correct or not, as well as my problem of displaying it.

```
def playerlist():
    req = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) #spoopy disguise
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

    soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    cleansoup = (soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))

    x = cleansoup.split("""Play time""")[-1]
    x = x.split("""Most Time Played""")[0]
    print(x)
```

```
@commands.hybrid_command(
        name="playerlist",
        description="This should pull a player list with playtimes",
    )
    # This will only allow non-blacklisted members to execute the command
    @checks.not_blacklisted()
    async def playerlist(self, context: Context) -> None:
        """
        playerlist from battlemetrics
        """
        playerlist()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Playerlist",
            description=x,
            color=0x9C84EF
        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
```

I get an error message saying that "x" is not defined. I can understand why it would say it is not defined but It is still confusing because it should have been defined from the function?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: the `x` the command sees and the function sees are different, try using `global x`

Answer (score 1):

you can return x from the playerlist function

```
def playerlist():
    req = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) #spoopy disguise
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()

    soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

    cleansoup = (soup.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))

    x = cleansoup.split("""Play time""")[-1]
    x = x.split("""Most Time Played""")[0]
    return x
```

and recalling it anytime

```
  @commands.hybrid_command(
        name="playerlist",
        description="This should pull a player list with playtimes",
    )
    # This will only allow non-blacklisted members to execute the command
    @checks.not_blacklisted()
    async def playerlist(self, context: Context) -> None:
        """
        playerlist from battlemetrics
        """
        x = playerlist()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Playerlist",
            description=x,
            color=0x9C84EF
        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
```